# レイヤーなら小数点を指定できる？

Tags: swift, ios

https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/ に `0.5` を指定しているところがあるので、同じようにできないか？ と聞かれ、`AutoLayout`（厳密には`UIView`）では、できない認識だったので、「できないな」と思ったのですが、公式のデザインリソースがそんなことをするのもおかしいと思い、よく見てみると、Inner Shadows の Y に `0.5` と `-0.5`が指定されていました。

他にも https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671379/1979953 で `CAGradientLayer` を操作していますが、`0.5`をしている箇所がありました。

`CALayer`なら小数点を指定してもよいものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まずCGRect、CGPoint、CGSizeなどビューの座標系の値に整数でない数値を指定できるかについていうと、指定できます。

相手がUIViewでもCALayerでも関係ありません。意味があるかどうかは別として（後述します）、0.5ポイント単位の座標や長さ、もっと細かい単位の数値を指定することもできます。

次に整数ではない値を指定した場合にどのような効果があるかを説明します。

参考資料としてこちらの[ドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7)、または[こちらの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016618/how-to-get-a-1-pixel-line-with-nsbezierpath)の図を見ると分かりやすいと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上の画像は前者のAppleのドキュメントに載っている図です。

iPhone 4が発売される前は１ポイントが画面の１ピクセルに対応していました。そのとき１ポイントの幅を持つ縦の線を描画することを考えます。

iOSのネイティブの描画システムでは指定した座標が中央に来るように線がひかれます（上記の図の右の例）。

この場合１ポイントを１ピクセルとして描画しようとすると左右のピクセル境界に調整されて２ピクセルの幅の線になってしまいます。合わせて１ピクセルの線を２ピクセルとして描画しているのでアンチエイリアスがかかります。

そうすると、１ピクセルのソリッドな線を描画したい場合には不適切でぼやけた２ピクセルの線が描画されてしまうことになります。
それを避けて、１ピクセルのソリッドな線を描画するにはOriginの座標を0.5ポイント、オフセットすると１ピクセルの幅の線がちょうどピクセル境界に一致するので１ピクセルのソリッドな線が描画されます（上の図の左の例。左端を0としてx方向を2.5ポイントと指定すると（`x: 2.5, y: 0, width: 1, height: 5`）2.5ポイントの中央を通る１ピクセルの線、が描けます）。

iPhone 4以降のRetina Displayでは１ポイントは２ピクセル以上になるので0.5ポイントのオフセットをしなくてもピクセル境界に合致した線が描画できます。

ただし、今度は物理的な画面で１ピクセルの極細線を描画したい場合に整数値ではできないので、0.5ポイント以下の幅や長さを指定する（DisplayのScaleの値を使って割ることが多い）ことで、１ピクセルの描画が実現できます。

まとめると、ネイティブの描画システムの特性を利用してピクセルの境界に合致してアンチエイリアスを避けたり、１ピクセルの細かい描画をしたい場合に整数ではない値を指定します。

Comment: `iPhone 4以降のRetina Displayでは１ポイントは２ピクセル以上`
という表現は `@2x` と `@3x` の場合についてをひとまとめにして表現したものと理解してよいでしょうか？

ご紹介いただいたAppleのドキュメントには Retina Display 1point = 2 pixels　とありますが、これは、`@2x`を想定している（おそらくこのドキュメントが書かれたときに `@3x` は存在しなかった）と考えてよいでしょうか？ `@3x` なら 1point = 3 pixels でしょうか?? なので `@2x`, `@3x` で状況が違うので
`DisplayのScaleの値を使って割ることが多い`
になるということでしょうか。

Comment: アンチエイリアスがかかる基準ですが、どんな端末であろうと、「左右のピクセル境界に一致しないところに配置された場合にアンチエイリアスをして強引に境界に一致させる」という認識で間違いないでしょうか？　この認識だと `@2x`の場合は 0.5ポイントの`幅`をセットすると、ぴったり1ピクセルになりますが、中央に配置されるので、左右の境界に一致せず、アンチエイリアスがかかってしまう？？（0.5オフセットして0.5の幅にするとアンチエイリアスなしでしょうか）

Comment: アンチエイリアスは厳密にはコントロールできる（そもそもデフォルトでは常にかかっている。ピクセル境界に合致している斜め方向でない直線の場合は結果的にON/OFFの見た目が変わらないだけ）ので問題はピクセル境界に調整されるかされないか、ですね。
@1xのデバイスの場合`(x: 3, y: 0, w: 1, h: 5)`という指定だと１ピクセルぴったりにはならない。１ピクセルの線を引きたいなら`(x: 2.5, y: 0, w: 1, h: 5)`とします。
@2xの場合`(x: 3, y: 0, w: 1, h: 5)`だと1pt == 2pxなので２ピクセルの線が引かれます。@3xは現状単純ではないです。説明が長くなるので省きましたがiPhone X等の@3xのデバイスは完全に３倍のピクセルにマッピングされるわけではありません（ディスプレイはそこまで高密度ではなく、物理的なピクセルが足りないので）。@3xのリソースをダウンスケールして表示されます。なので単純ではないですが、理屈は一緒です。ヘアラインと言われる物理的に1pxの線を描画するには1pt以下の幅を指定します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理屈がわかり、1pxの線が描けました。

Comment: 補足：「iPhone X等の@3xのデバイスは」→「iPhone 8 Plus等の@3xのデバイスは」とのことです https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/66822/19110